# Concurrent Unity Scenes with SceneManager

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to run multiple scenes concurrently with Unity's new `SceneManager` system?

To clarify, I mean completely separate environments, not by using MergeScenes (Behaves similar to the old LoadLevelAdditive function) to put two scenes in one.

Comment: sure, it's exactly the same except the syntax has changed

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Because LoadLevelAdditive is deprecated you should migrate ur code to use LoadScene. Just change the LoadSceneMode parameter to Additive. Example:

```
public static void LoadScene("foo", SceneManagement.Additive);
```

Font:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html